# PHP socket connect from external IP problem

Tags: php, sockets, ubuntu

i have a problem with PHP Socket connect on an ubuntu-server with PHP7 behind NAT. I can connect from all devices in local-network (192.168.2.XXX) with telnet. But i cannot connect from external IP from Internet. PORT 5555 is open in firewall and i can see traffic coming in with "tcpdump". but PHP is ignoring this. Here is my code so far:

```
$port = 5555;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP) or die("socket_create failed");
socket_bind($socket,'0.0.0.0',$port) or die("socket_bind failed");
socket_listen($socket);

while(true)
{
    if(($newc = socket_accept($socket)) !== false)
    {
                echo "connected ...";
                socket_close($newc);
    }
}
socket_close($socket);
```

Thanks ahead for your help...

Dave

Comment: Have you configured port forwarding from the NAT router to the machine running PHP?

Comment: First, use some tiny little 3rd party software like Packet Sender in listen mode to make sure TCP packets are reaching up to your server. Then go review your code.

Comment: Yes portforwarding ist enabled. I can see datapackets on ubuntu server with tcpdump but only incoming not outgoing. I will try 3rd party software @broken arrow said and will look whats happening

Comment: Also I think you cannot rely over '$newc' as a client connection that way, rather it needs to be an array of client connections, otherwise, as soon as a new client connects, you will lose the rest of the previous connections, resulting into forfeiting the concurrent multi client feature you expect from a socket server.